# how to get an amount yearly from the starting year in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query to get a sum amount for yearly from the contract start date.

Ex: If the contract started in 2018 and ended in 2020 so i need the sum of due_amount for each year in select query.

```
select annual_amount_1,annual_amuont2_annual_amount_3
from dual..


Here i need o/p in annual_amount_1 as-> sum(due_amount_in 2018)
                   annual_amount_2 as-> sum(due_amount_in 2019)
                   annual_amount_3 as-> sum(due_amount_in 2020)
```

how to achieve this in select query

Comment: Please include actual sample data in your question.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  `dual` does not have the columns you specify.  Your unnamed name would seem to have two date columns, but that is not clear.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case-when` statement:

```
select your_columns,
SUM(case when to_char(your_date,'YY') = 18 then your_amount) as amount_18,
SUM(case when to_char(your_date,'YY') = 19 then your_amount) as amount_19,
SUM(case when to_char(your_date,'YY') = 20 then your_amount) as amount_20

FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t1 (
d DATE,
a NUMBER
);

INSERT into t1 (d, a) VALUES (DATE '2020-08-01', 22);

INSERT into t1 (d, a) VALUES (DATE '2020-09-01', 42);

INSERT into t1 (d, a) VALUES (DATE '2021-08-01', 111);

INSERT into t1 (d, a) VALUES (DATE '2021-09-01', 222);


SELECT to_char(d, 'YYYY') as year, SUM(a) sum from t1
GROUP by  to_char(d, 'YYYY')
Order by  to_char(d, 'YYYY')
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.